# locating the position of points in imageView to larger image

Tags: ios, math, opencv, geometry

I'm working on app that needs user interaction to locate some points in image. because the image apear smaller in the app , I need to transform the points locations to a larger image. so I need the math to do so. to transform points to a larger image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

smaller image dimensions: `Ws x Hs`
bigger image dimensions: `Wb x Hb`

user taps smaller image at `(Xs,Ys)`

appropriate point on the bigger image `(Xb,Yb)` would be:

```
Xb = Xs * (Wb/Ws);
Yb = Ys * (Hb/Hs);
```

And for the other way around:

```
Xs = Xb / (Wb/Ws);
Ys = Yb / (Hb/Hs);
```

Comment: How about the other way around ? is it the same ?

Comment: @MujtabaAlboori: i edited the answer for the other way around also